Tail.select Dropdown Popup Behind
Im having issue with my tail.select dropdown. I have 2 tail select elements on top of each other. But the first element, pop up its dropdown behind the second one. If the second element is not a tail.select plugin, it is okay.

I need the dropdown of the first tail select element to appear on top of the second one.
